# Creating a mysql table view that "merges" two columns from a table depending on its values and select its most recent date from a DateTime type column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a MySQL database table like this:

| ID | ref_A | ref_B | ref_Id | dateLog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | XX | 2019-12-20 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | XX | 2020-12-25 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | XX | 2021-04-01 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | YY | 2021-04-12 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | YY | 2021-04-13 |

I want to create a table view that treats occurrences of combination between two columns as a unique "relationship" and select date of its most recent occurrence. We see above that combinations between "5" and "2" are repeated 3 times, even if it were thousands combinations, I need to treat that as 1 single relation, as if I was saying(2 is participating of event XX, 5 is participating of event XX, 2 is also participating of event YY... etc) and also having its last date of ocurrence, so my desired table view would be:

| ref_Combined | ref_Id | lastUpdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | XX | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | XX | 2021-04-01 |
| 3 | YY | 2021-04-13 |
| 2 | YY | 2021-04-13 |

I have no idea of how can I mount the select inside "CREATE VIEW vw_Table AS (...)". Could someone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want the results as two *row*s instead of being in one row.  So, I would recommend:

```
select least(ref_A, ref_B), greatest(ref_A, ref_B), ref_id,
       max(date_log)
from t
group by least(ref_A, ref_B), greatest(ref_A, ref_B), ref_id;
```

If you want a particular id, then add:

```
where 5 in (ref_A, ref_B)
```

If you really need this unpivoted, you could use:

```
select least(ref_A, ref_B) as ref_Combined, ref_id, max(date_log)
from t
group by least(ref_A, ref_B), greatest(ref_A, ref_B), ref_id
union all
select greatest(ref_A, ref_B) as ref_Combined, ref_id, max(date_log)
from t
group by least(ref_A, ref_B), greatest(ref_A, ref_B), ref_id;
```

Comment: Hi, Gordon. Thank you for your answer. I need that because I will do something like this in the result:  ```select ref_id from T where ref_combined=5```and get all the relations that "5" is participating.

Comment: @SandroBenevides . . . You can check for `5` using a `where` clause.  That should speed up any query.

Comment: But that would be done at execution time each time an user logs in with his own ID, right? A table view with all values done, awaiting for being seek wouldn't faster, since the table view is partially done?

Comment: I mean, a table view is persistent( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL) ), right? So it's faster look for a ref_id where 5 is participating than seeking at whole main table. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SandroBenevides . . . That is generally true.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT LEAST(ref_a, ref_b) ref_Combined, 
       ref_Id,
       MAX(dateLog) lastUpdate
FROM test
GROUP BY LEAST(ref_a, ref_b), GREATEST(ref_a, ref_b), ref_id
UNION ALL
SELECT GREATEST(ref_a, ref_b), 
       ref_Id,
       MAX(dateLog)
FROM test
GROUP BY LEAST(ref_a, ref_b), GREATEST(ref_a, ref_b), ref_id
ORDER BY ref_Id, ref_Combined DESC
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80ed31679ba93fb8c7dc80c305854be0

Convert to a view by yourself - this work is not hard.